# The positive definitiveness of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite, block-matrices

$\mathbb{Q}\in\mathbb{S}^{Nm\times Nm}$ ($\mathbb{S}$ denotes the symmtric matrix), $Q\in\mathbb{S}^{m\times m}$, $Q\geq 0$. Can we find some large $M$ such that for $N>M$ we always have $\mathbb{Q}\geq 0$? If no, what about $Q> 0$?
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
    \mathbb{Q}\triangleq&\begin{smallmatrix}1\\\vdots\\\vdots\\N\end{smallmatrix}
    \left(\begin{smallmatrix}
      Q & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
      0 & Q  & \cdots & 0 \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\
      0 & 0 & \cdots & Q \\
    \end{smallmatrix}\right) - \frac{1}{N}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
      Q & Q & \cdots & Q \\
      Q & Q & \cdots & Q \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\
      Q & Q & \cdots & Q \\
    \end{smallmatrix}\right)
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
It is related to my research. If this result holds true, then it will help me save a lot of works. Otherwise, I should prove my result via another tidious way. Thus, I really appreciate your concerning. Thank you very much!

If $N = 2^n$, I have proved that $\mathbb{Q}\geq 0$ if $Q\geq 0$ by using the following result to computate its eigenvalue.
\begin{equation}
\det\left(\begin{smallmatrix}A&B\\B&A\end{smallmatrix}\right) = \det(A-B)\det(A+B)
\end{equation}

However, I cannot get a further result.

Edited

Consider a arbitrary vector $x = (x^T_1,\cdots,x_N^T)^T$. Then
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
    x^T\mathbb{Q}x=&x^T\begin{smallmatrix}1\\\vdots\\\vdots\\N\end{smallmatrix}
    \left(\begin{smallmatrix}
      Q & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
      0 & Q  & \cdots & 0 \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\
      0 & 0 & \cdots & Q \\
    \end{smallmatrix}\right)x - \frac{1}{N}x^T\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
      Q & Q & \cdots & Q \\
      Q & Q & \cdots & Q \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\
      Q & Q & \cdots & Q \\
    \end{smallmatrix}\right)x\\
=&(x^T_1Qx_1+\cdots+x_N^TQx_N) - \frac{1}{N}(x_1+\cdots+x_N)^TQ(x_1+\cdots+x_N)\\
\color{red}\geq&(x^T_1Qx_1+\cdots+x_N^TQx_N) - \frac{1}{N}\left(N(x^T_1Qx_1+\cdots+x_N^TQx_N)\right)\geq 0
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
The red $\color{red}\geq$ holds if $Q\geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble with the notation. By $Q>0$, do you mean all entries are positive? If so, how do you expect to find a number, for which $0-Q_{ij}\geq 0$? Also, what is the vector written to the left of the diagonal matrix?
Also, the last identity with the determinant is false. The correct result would be $det(A-BA^{-1}B)\cdot det(A)$

Comment: Dear UnexpectedExpectation,  Thank you for your concern! First, $Q>0$ denotes that $Q$ is strictly positive definite. Second, the vector $1......N$ denote the number of the rows of the matrix. Last, the result of $det(A−B)det(A+B)$ comes from wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant   the blocks A B are square matrices of the same order  Thank you!